# Is it possible to overclock the polling rate for a wireless mouse?

Tags: windows-7, usb, mouse, overclocking

I have a Logitech Performance Mouse MX -- a wireless laser mouse. From a diagnostic program, I can see that the polling rate is 125Hz. I'd like to overclock this to 500Hz (or however higher it can go above 125Hz).

I've seen articles on how to overclock the polling rate on a USB port, however, they seem to be dealing with wired devices. Could a wireless mouse benefit from a polling rate overclock?

I'm wondering if the extra variable of a wireless connection between mouse movement and cursor movement is going to preclude a faster polling rate.

Comment: Unless the specific mouse supports changing the polling rate, it is not possible.

Comment: So is it a matter of overclocking the mouse, or overclocking the USB port? The guides seem to point to the USB port as the limiting factor that needs overclocking, and that gaming-mice actually do this -- overclocking the USB port behind the scenes.

Comment: Well, you don't need to make the USB port faster as mice don't require that much bandwidth. Consider that each mouse data packet is at most 256 bytes so at 125Hz that's only 31.25KB/s and at 500Hz only 125KB/s both lower than even USB 1's Low-Bandwidth mode of 192KB/s.

Comment: @Coldblackice: It's not really overclocking, it's simply changing the [rate at which the driver polls](http://www.ngohq.com/news/15043-how-to-increase-usb-sample-rate-in-windows-vista-7-a.html) the USB port. Is your OS 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: 64-bit. What's confused me is how the overclocking guides seem to be targeting Windows' USB drivers, rather than mouse drivers. So I assumed it was an issue of the USB port/driver being the limiting factor.

Comment: Even if you found a way for the sensor to poll at a faster rate, you'd need to modify the mouse to transmit data faster, too.